# Can I run a service in the background on Wear OS, constantly sending heart rate data via WiFi/LTE?

Tags: service, background, wifi, wear-os

Is it possible on Wear OS to constantly record heart rate data and/or other sensor data in the background and send it via WiFi/4G without a phone?

Can such a service start on boot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - but if long lived you must use passive updates to get batched data, otherwise you will likely ruin battery life.

https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/health-services

https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/health-services/passive

You can request an LTE or Wifi network to sned data when you have enough to send.  But you shouldn't try to keep the network open permanently.

Comment: What if i need the data in real time? I cannot really wait until the next batch? What wait time would be sufficient here?